# After executing Membership.ValidateUser, the roles and userroles are cleared and returns nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, forms-authentication, user-roles

I am having a strange problem. I am using c# asp.net with forms authentication with **Mysql**. 
The website has 2 folders insite the root, "User" and "Admin".

I have created a test user using the asp net configuration tool and properly set up the permissions to the folders.

I am using the Login control with custom code in the authenticate event.

```
    protected void Login1_Authenticate1(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
        {
            e.Authenticated = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Authenticated = false;
        }
    }
```

As soon as the Membership.ValidateUser function executes all the roles are cleared and nothing is assigned to the logged in user (although the user logs in successfully)

I have set up a watch and a break point before Membership.ValidateUser.

**Before running ValidateUser:**

```
    Roles.GetAllRoles() {string[2]} string[]
```

**After running ValidateUser:**

```
    Roles.GetAllRoles() {string[0]} string[]
```

The user does log in successfully but cannot access either folder (the user does have access to both roles, confirmed by looking in the database)

What I have noticed as well is that if I modify the web.config file after the user is logged in and save it (while the website is still running) then the Roles are all populated again and the user can

**Here is the root web.config file:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="MySqlMembershipConnection" connectionString="Data Source=XXXX;user id=XXXX;password=XXXX;database=XXXX;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
        </connectionStrings>
        <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
           <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" timeout="15"
              cookieless="UseCookies" />
        </authentication>

            <membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
                <providers>
                    <clear/> 
                    <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, mysql.web" connectionStringName="MySqlMembershipConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" autogenerateschema="true"/>
                </providers>
            </membership>

          <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="MySqlRoleProvider" cookieName=".ASPXROLES" cookiePath="/" cookieTimeout="15" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" createPersistentCookie="false" cookieProtection="All">
                <providers>
                    <clear/>
                    <add connectionStringName="MySqlMembershipConnection" applicationName="/" name="MySqlRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, mysql.web" autogenerateschema="true"/>
                </providers>
            </roleManager>

            <profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySqlRoleProvider">
                <providers>
                    <clear/>
                    <add type="MySql.Web.Security.MySqlProfileProvider, mysql.web" name="MySqlProfileProvider" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="MySqlMembershipConnection" autogenerateschema="true"/>
                </providers>
            </profile>
            <compilation debug="true"/></system.web>
        <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"></validation>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

**Admin Folder web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Admin" />
        <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

**User Folder web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.web>
        <authorization>
        <allow roles="User" />
        <allow roles="Admin" />
        <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
        </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Please can someone point me into a direction here, this seems more like a bug than a programming error, but I would like to hear your possible solutions.